# How could I change java.lang.Enum's ordinal when using JPA and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, enums

**The Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class MyClass extends IdEntity {
    private MyEnumType enumType;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
public MyEnumType getEnumType() {
    return enumType;
}

public void setEnumType(MyEnumType enumType) {
    this.enumType= enumType;
}
}
```

**The Enum:**

```
public enum MyEnumType {
    DOG(11),CAT(13),BULL(20);
    private int value;
    private MyEnumType (int value) {
    this.value= value;
}
    public int getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value= value;
}
}
```

**The Main Code:**

```
//any code then ...
entity.setsEnumType(MyEnumType.CAT);
//...persist API
```

I want to persist the cat's int value(**13**) in the database(e.g. mysql).But in mysql,the enumType is （**1**）,what is the ORDINAL value.I wonder is there a way to store my custom value by JPA and spring???

There is a way like this:

`change "private MyEnumType enumType;"   to  "private **int** enumType;"`

Then:

`entity.setsEnumType(MyEnumType.CAT.getValue());`

But I don't like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA 2.1 allows defining custom types in a standard way. Using the [@Convert](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html) annotation. See http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/2013/10/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter.html for an explanation, is the javadoc is not sufficient.

If you're still using JPA 2.0, then Hibernate has a proprietary way of defining [custom types](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#types-custom).